# WATIN-Run script Problem in IIS

Tags: watin, iis-5

I am using watin framwork. I have wrote code ie.Runscript('newnote()'); Its running in my pc IIS success. This code also runnign with client visual studio 2008 with success but failed with client IIS. I have also set all rights in IIS and web folder. also check with IE7 and IE8. We have verfied with SSL certificate.But we can not identify where is problem.

please, help me.

Error: (1) Run script failed. and some time (2)Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Code Like:

string mfnQS='45SDS82'

string noteURL = string.Format  ("https://sitename.co.uk/apps/shared/dlg_addnoteform.jsp?{0}&parent_package=cxa&cid=", mfnQS);
                    ie.GoTo(noteURL);
                    ie.WaitForComplete(2000);
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    objBO.NoteDetails = objBO.NoteDetails;

```
                string sNote = StringUtility.RemoveHtmlTag(objBO.NoteDetails);  

                TextField notetext = ie.TextField(Find.ById("notetext"));  
                notetext.WaitUntilExists(2000);  

                notetext.Value = sNote;  
                notetext.WaitForComplete();  

                ie.RunScript("$('iframe').contents().find('html body').html(document.addnote.notetext.value)");  

                WatiN.Core.Button btnAdd = ie.Button(Find.ByValue("ADD NOTE"));  
                if (btnAdd.Exists)  
                {  
                    if (ClsReadOnlyKeyword.IsFinalVersion)  
                    {  
                        ie.RunScript("newnote();");  
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);  
                        isTrue = true;  
                    }  
                }
```